# sql query with \ as value to check

Tags: mysql, sql, special-characters

I have a query in the following way.....i have a column named location_ns and it contains 
'Marriott\256 Hotel & Convention Centre'  as it's value. But query is not resulting any id.
when i remove \ in both value and query it is working.

```
SELECT id
FROM notice
WHERE 
lon = 78.48693966865540000000 
AND lat = 17.42434596639255000000 
AND location_ns = 'Marriott\256 Hotel & Convention Centre' 
AND notice_type="text"
```

Please let me know if any one has a solution for it

Comment: Try to escape it using two \'s instead of one: `Marriott\\256 Hotel & Convention Centre`

Comment: how silly of me...how did i forget that??? thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html):

> Within a string, certain sequences have special meaning unless the [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) SQL mode is enabled. Each of these sequences begins with a backslash (“`\`”), known as the *escape character*. MySQL recognizes the escape sequences shown in [Table 9.1, “Special Character Escape Sequences”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences). For all other escape sequences, backslash is ignored. That is, the escaped character is interpreted as if it was not escaped. For example, “`\x`” is just “`x`”.

Therefore, you must escape your backslash:

```
AND location_ns = 'Marriott\\256 Hotel & Convention Centre'
```

However, you would do well to pass your literals to MySQL as parameters to a [prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496).

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an escape sequence in MySQL.  If you had a record with value:

```
Marriott\256 Hotel & Convention Centre
```

You would need to query for it like

```
AND location_ns = 'Marriott\\256 Hotel & Convention Centre'
```

This let's MySQL know you are looking for a literal `\`.